# button doesnt work after load partialview with AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

i have a page that have two buttons Next and Previos. This buttons load a table in a PartialView. 
My problem is when i press the button second time, it doesnt work.

Here is the code

The View :

```
<div id="Centros">
                <div class="divPantalla2">
                    <table cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                                Nombre
                            </th>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                                Nro- Establecimiento
                            </th>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                                Departamento
                            </th>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                                Localidad
                            </th>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @if (ViewBag.OnePageOfCEProyecto != null)
                        {



                            foreach (ANEP.Models.CentroEducativoModel item in ViewBag.OnePageOfCEProyecto)
                            {

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Nombre
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.NroEstablecimiento
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @if (item.dDepartamento != null)
                                    {
                                        @item.dDepartamento.Descripcion;
                                    }
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @if (item.dLocalidad != null)
                                    {
                                        @item.dLocalidad.NomLocalidad;
                                    }
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button  type="submit" value="Eliminar+@item.CEID"  name="Command" class="btn_eliminar">
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>         
                            }

                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="botones">
                    @if (ViewBag.OnePageOfCEProyecto != null)
                    {
                        <div align="center">
                            <div align="center">
                                @if (Session["PROYECTO_PAGINA_ACTUAL"] != null && int.Parse(Session["PROYECTO_PAGINA_ACTUAL"].ToString()) > 1)
                                {

                                    <button type="button" id="Primera" value="Primera1" name="Command" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <font color="#0C58A8"><<</font></button>

                                    <button type="button" id="Anterior" value="Anterior1" name="Command" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <font color="#0C58A8"><</font></button>
                                }
                                <font color="#0C58A8">@int.Parse(Session["PROYECTO_PAGINA_ACTUAL"].ToString())</font>
                                @if (ViewBag.OnePageOfCEProyecto.Count == 8)
                                {

                                    <button type="button" id="Siguiente" value="Siguiente1" name="Command" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <font color="#0C58A8">></font></button>

                                    <button type="button" id="Ultima" value="Ultima1" name="Command" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <font color="#0C58A8">>></font></button>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
```

The PartialView :

```
                <div class="divPantalla2">
                    <table cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover table-responsive     table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                                Nombre
                            </th>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                                Nro- Establecimiento
                            </th>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                                Departamento
                            </th>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                                Localidad
                            </th>
                            <th class="thTablas">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @if (ViewBag.OnePageOfCEProyecto != null)
                        {



                            foreach (ANEP.Models.CentroEducativoModel item in ViewBag.OnePageOfCEProyecto)
                            {

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Nombre
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.NroEstablecimiento
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @if (item.dDepartamento != null)
                                    {
                                        @item.dDepartamento.Descripcion;
                                    }
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @if (item.dLocalidad != null)
                                    {
                                        @item.dLocalidad.NomLocalidad;
                                    }
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button  type="submit" value="Eliminar+@item.CEID"  name="Command" class="btn_eliminar">
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>         
                            }

                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="botones">
                    @if (ViewBag.OnePageOfCEProyecto != null)
                    {
                        <div align="center">
                            <div align="center">
                                @if (Session["PROYECTO_PAGINA_ACTUAL"] != null && int.Parse(Session["PROYECTO_PAGINA_ACTUAL"].ToString()) > 1)
                                {

                                    <button type="button" id="Primera" value="Primera1" name="Command" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <font color="#0C58A8"><<</font></button>

                                    <button type="button" id="Anterior" value="Anterior1" name="Command" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <font color="#0C58A8"><</font></button>
                                }
                                <font color="#0C58A8">@int.Parse(Session["PROYECTO_PAGINA_ACTUAL"].ToString())</font>
                                @if (ViewBag.OnePageOfCEProyecto.Count == 8)
                                {

                                    <button type="button" id="Siguiente" value="Siguiente1" name="Command" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <font color="#0C58A8">></font></button>

                                    <button type="button" id="Ultima" value="Ultima1" name="Command" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <font color="#0C58A8">>></font></button>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
```

The AJAX function (only for the button next):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Siguiente").on("click", function () {
            var accion = $('#Siguiente').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Proyecto/TablaCentros",
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                data: { command: accion }
            })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#Centros").html(partialViewResult);
        });
        });
    });
```

And the controller :

```
public ActionResult TablaCentros(string command, Proyecto p)
    {
        if (command != null)
        {
            if (command.Contains("Siguiente1"))
            {
                if (Session["REGISTRO_PROYECTO"] != null)
            {
                Proyecto model = p;
                int page = (int)Session["PROYECTO_PAGINA_ACTUAL"];
                page++;
                Session["PROYECTO_PAGINA_ACTUAL"] = page;
                List<CentroEducativoModel> lista =   (List<CentroEducativoModel>)Session["PROYECTO_CENTRO_EDUCATIVOS"];
                var onePageOfCEProyecto = lista.ToPagedList(page, 8); // will only contain 15 products max because of the pageSize
                ViewBag.OnePageOfCEProyecto = onePageOfCEProyecto;
                cargarEstadoProyecto();
                cargarCentroEducativos();
                cargarClaseProyecto();
                cargarTipoProyecto();
                return PartialView("_TablaCentros", model);
            }
            }
        }
        return PartialView("_TablaCentros");
    }
```

Sorry for my English,

Thanks!!!

Comment: It looks like your view and your partial view are the same. Are they?

Comment: yes, because the first time my page load the table with some elements, but when you press next, the page load the parial view with differents data

Comment: If that is the case, then I would recommend you include the partial onto your page. This way you only have the code in one place and avoid duplicating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your buttons are part of your partial view.  When you initially load your view (without ajax) your button is bound to your click handler and all is well.  When you click that button, your handler fires, makes the request and then replaces the #Centros content with the response -- however your bound button is part of the content that is replaced and your "new" buttons aren't bound.

You will need to rebind your handlers to your buttons after the ajax request has completed and you've loaded the result.  You have a couple of options -- you can move your script to your partial view so it would fire after it's loaded, you can call your binding code in your done() handler or you can change your selector for your existing code to [use a delegate](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data).

I would use the delegate which would look similar to this:

```
$("#Centros").on("click", "#Siguiente", function() { ... })
```

This essentially means that anytime a click event happens in #Centros to an element with an ID of #Siguiente then handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

I hope what ny answer will help you. What I have noticed in the signature of your Action in the controller it is supposed to receive two arguments `command` and `Proyecto` but on your ajax function you just pass `command:accion` So your Action does not receive the object `Proyecto`.